# Why is my nav-pill on the top of my screen in IE & Edge but it looks fine in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a simple web page, but on google chrome it looks perfectly fine, just how I want, but when I open the page in IE or Edge the nav-pill tabs are at the top of the screen instead of near the middle like they are in chrome.

**Images:**
[image: Chrome]

[image: IE & Edge]

I have the 'top' property of the div that they are in is set to 30%.

I have a lot more code, but I don't want to flood this with it, If you need more info let me know! Thanks in advance!

```
#bodyArea
{
    width: 425px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    left: 44.3%;    
}
```

Comment: All the properties you gave us in the `#bodyArea` are compatible with both  IE6+ & Chrome v.1+. So the matter is not here, you should paste you complete code or at least a sample of your code showing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After testing the code you showed us i noticed as well that it didn't work in IE. From here i would conclude the percentage from top for position:relative is incompatible with IE (judging from this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531177(v=vs.85).aspx IE takes a percentage of the parent container and it might not know the height of the container of your div). I am afraid i can't be of more help without knowing more of the code around your div.